# Creating a CMake Find Package

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to create a find_package file for Texas Instruments development boards. This is the code.

```
set(TIVAWARE_DIR $ENV{TIVAWARE})

if (NOT TIVAWARE_DIR)
  message(STATUS "TIVAWARE_DIR not set")
endif()

message(STATUS "Found TivaWare at ${TIVAWARE_DIR}")

find_path(TIVAWARE_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES tm4c123gh6pm.h
  HINTS ${TIVAWARE_DIR}/inc
  DOC "The TivaWare include directory."
)
message(STATUS "==== ${TIVAWARE_INCLUDE_DIR}")

find_library(TIVAWARE_LIBRARY_DIR
  NAMES libdriver
  HINTS ${TIVAWARE_DIR}/driverlib/gcc
  DOC "The TivaWare driver library path."
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(TIVAWARE DEFAULT_MSG TIVAWARE_INCLUDE_DIR TIVAWARE_LIBRARY_DIR)

if(TIVAWARE_FOUNT)
  set(TIVAWARE_LIBRARIES ${TIVAWARE_LIBRARY_DIR})
  set(TIVAWARE_INCLUDE_DIRS ${TIVAWARE_INCLUDE_DIR})
  set(TIVAWARE_DEFINITIONS)
endif()

mark_as_advanced(TIVAWARE_INCLUDE_DIR TIVAWARE_LIBRARY_DIR)
```

The environment variable is defined and found by this file. But it fails to find the include and library files. This is a portion of the output I get.

```
Cross-compiling with the gcc-arm-embedded toolchain
Toolchain prefix: e:/armtm/armgcc/arm-none-eabi
Eclipse version is set to 3.6 (Helios). Adjust CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION if this is wrong.
Found TivaWare at e:\armtm\swtm4c
==== TIVAWARE_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
```

I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Actually you really shouldn't write these scripts. They're a complete waste of time.

Do you work for Texas Instruments? If you do, there are better ways than these Find*.cmake scripts.

If you don't, just do

```
set(TIVAWARE_INCLUDE_DIR "${TIVAWARE_DIR}/inc" CACHE PATH "")
```

and get back to getting work done. :)

Comment: Thanks for your input, that is one way of doing it. But if I create a new project I will have to add all those **set** statements (not only include directories - there are a number of library files as well). If I have a FindXXXX.cmake module it work is done and I simply have to call the find_package statement.

Could you explain why you say they are a wast of time?

Comment: If you must you can call `set` in the Find*.cmake. I don't like these scripts because it shouldn't be the job of the library user to write these scripts. It's a system designed from the ground up to be broken. But if you have to do it, keep it as simple as possible. In your script you specify one possible subdirectory for `lib` and `inc`, so why bother calling `find_path`, which has possibly random behavior due to their weird `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` mechanics.

Comment: Thanks, I got the script to work after editing it quite a bit but I also had to place it in the CMake modules directory, which I don't like. I'll accept you answer.

Comment: @user1240182 What I do is `get_filename_component(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "./CMake" ABSOLUTE CACHE)` at the beginning of the top-most `CMakeLists.txt`. You can place the `Find*.cmake` scripts there.